# Счетчик текущего онлайна на сайте

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование, websocket, next.js

Каким образом лучше всего реализовать отслеживания текущего онлайна на сайте?

В качестве сервера использую **NextJS**, думал делать через веб-сокеты, но мне кажется есть идея намного лучше.

Отправлять постоянно на сервер запрос, что человек онлайн - кажется глупым.

Или как это, например, реализовано на [Twitch](https://www.twitch.tv/)?

Буду рад услышать любые предложения

Comment: Могу оказаться не прав, но мне представляется это так... При каком либо действии пользователя в таблицу БД пишется текущий идентификатор пользователя и время. Для отображения количества пользователей опрашивается таблица с ограничением времени (нпример, записи не старше 15 минут). Для пользователей, которые зарегистрированны, можно добавить в таблицу свойство/колонку, по которому можно будет подсчитывать отдельно зарегистрированных пользователей и просто "гостей". Также можно добавить поля для имени пользователя, тогда можно будет не только показывать количество, но и кто конкретно на сайте.

Comment: UPD: Нашёл ещё  такой способ
window.addEventListener("unload", function() {
  //code
});

При закрытии окна браузера выполнит код

Comment: "При закрытии окна браузера выполнит код" - а смысл? Т.е. пользователь не увидит сам себя в списке пользователей, которые сейчас онлайн. А если страница не будет выгружаться? Например в SPA?

Comment: Увидит, сервер будет фиксировать нового при запросе на страницу и удалять при уходе